# Can I Download my website articles, Images, and all content in one click?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, plugins, developer-tools

Is there a specific tool or software that is recommended for downloading website content in one click?

I want to download my website all articles and images.

Answer (score -1):

it sounds like you want to make some kind of backup. If your site is on Wordpress, you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/).

If you have a custom site that is not build over any platform and you don't have any FTP access to it - you still have an option to download manualy every single page by right-clicking on the webapge and selecting "Save As". This will save locally all the data of the webpage - including texts, styles and images (not the perfect way, but still good if you don't have any other options).